# React router scrolls new page down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I came across an issue using `react-router ^2.4.1` where if I scroll down on my home page and afterwards go to a new page it will also be scrolled down, as opposed to being at the top (expected behaviour).

I am using this starter pack: [react-webpack-node](https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node) and my routes.jsx looks like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import cookie from 'react-cookie'

import App from 'containers/App'
import HomePage from 'containers/HomePage'
import WaitingListPage from 'containers/WaitingListPage'
import NotFoundPage from 'containers/NotFoundPage'
import SupportPage from 'containers/SupportPage'

/*
 * @param {Redux Store}
 * We require store as an argument here because we wish to get
 * state from the store after it has been authenticated.
 */
export default (store) => {
  const hasQueueToken = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    if (cookie.load('queueToken')) {
      replace({
        pathname: `/waiting-list/${cookie.load('queueToken')}`,
        state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
      })
    }
    callback()
  }

  return (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
      <Route path='/w_ref/:ref' component={HomePage} />
      <Route path='/waiting-list/:token' component={WaitingListPage} />
      <Route path='/waiting-list' onEnter={hasQueueToken} component={WaitingListPage} />
      <Route path='/support' component={SupportPage} />
      <Route path='/terms-and-conditions' component={TermsConditions} />
      <Route path='/privacy-policy' component={PrivacyPolicy} />
      <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Route>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Router does not include scroll state management starting in version 2.0.0.

The recommended approach is to decorate the router with `scroll-behavior` using `react-router-scroll` as seen [in this example](https://github.com/taion/react-router-scroll#usage):

```
import { applyRouterMiddleware, browserHistory, Router } from 'react-router';
import useScroll from 'react-router-scroll';

/* ... */

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router
    history={browserHistory}
    routes={routes}
    render={applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll())}
  />,
  container
);
```

Comment: Thanks I have this working great. Just wondering if there's a way to scrollToBottom on page load of route X.

Answer (score 0):

[@John Trichereau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823124/john-trichereau):

scrolling to bottom can be done by giving a callback to `useScroll`, your callback would look like:

```
function customScroll (prevRouterProps, location) {
  // on route /foo scroll to bottom
  if (location.pathname == '/foo') return 'fooBottomDiv';
  // on all other routes, follow useScroll default behavior
  return prevRouterProps && location.pathname !== prevRouterProps.location.pathname;
}
```

and you would pass it to your router like this:

```
<Router render={ applyRouterMiddleware(useScroll((prevRouterProps, { location }) => customScroll(prevRouterProps, location))) }>
```

In your page, you would need to insert an invisible div with id `fooBottomDiv`. If you don't want to insert such a div, then you can have `customScroll` return a 2-element array `[x, y]` which could be `[0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]` to scroll to bottom.

Documentation [here](https://github.com/taion/react-router-scroll#custom-scroll-behavior)

Note however that if your page has a component which loads data and displays it, it will most likely not work as the `customScroll` function is only called upon route matching, whereas your data is probably called asynchronously and received after route matching.
In this case, it's most convenient to use

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.fooBottomDiv).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

in React lifecycle methods `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, where your component would contain an empty div with `ref` attribute `ref='fooBottomDiv`.